# Linking to jquery script file from master page or default page in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm working with jquery ui in asp.net web forms I have loaded the libraries and everything is working ok but i can only run the scripts by placing the script in the head section of the master page or the default page. I cant seem to link to an external script file and run the script from it.

I have this in the head of my master page:

```
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  <script src="Scripts/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--this does not load -->
  <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="Scripts/css/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   />
```

I have tried various things but it doesn't seem to work

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your script cannot be found because of the relative location from the master page.

Try

```
 <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: the jQuery library scripts load ok its the script file myscript.js that wont load ? I'm not at my machine at moment but will try this later and update . Many thanks